# Compare and print out the rows which meet the conditions

Tags: excel

I would like to compare the latest date for each `Name`, and only print out the result without duplication of `Name`, one `Name` only with latest `PurchaseDate` and `Type`. Any method can be used?
Example:

```
Name PurchaseDate  Type
Alex 10-3-2011     A  
Alex 3-7-2014      B
Alex 25-12-2013    C
Jim  27-2-2014     C
Jim  1-10-2012     D
Jim  2-3-2013      A
```

.
.
.

Expected Result:

```
Name PurchaseDate  Type
Alex 3-7-2014      B
Jim  27-2-2014     C
```

.
.
.

Comment: if sort by date, i cannot remove the duplicate Name. the output is a Name (no duplicate Name, eg One Alex, and One Jim will be appeared in list) with the latest Date only. I have a very long list to sort out...

Answer (score 0):

Sort by Name and Purchase Date Oldest to Newest, add this formula:

```
=IF(A2<>A3,"keep","")
```

(say in D2 and copied down), filter and for column D in the example, check "keep" then print.

[image: SO23651456 example]